# Comitar um arquivo da pasta vendor

Tags: git, commit

Minha pasta vendor é por padrão ignorada e sei que esse é o certo, mas acontece que preciso comitar um arquivo específico que se encontra nessa pasta, teria como? Se não tiver, que outra solução posso adotar?

Comment: `git add vendor/nome-da-pasta`

Comment: A pasta vendor serve literamente para software produzido por terceiro, você pode tentar fazer um pull request da sua alteração para o autor original ou caso ele não goste ou você não tenha interesse em contribuir você pode fazer um fork do original e trabalhar com o fork

Comment: Vou considerar fazer isso @RafaelMenaBarreto, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o arquivo estiver como ignorado, você pode forçar a adição desses arquivos:

```
git add --force -- arquivo1 arquivo2
git commit -m "adicionar arquivos anteriormente ignorados"
git push
```

Se quiser adicionar todos os arquivos para um `commit`, exceto um único arquivo:

```
git add -u
git reset -- pasta/arquivo.txt
```

Veja mais na [Documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

Comment: Essa solução me ajudará bastante no momento, muito obrigado!

Comment: @RaylanSoares, de nada =)